# How to compare aging of material samples

Tags: r, time-series, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference

I have a data set of 300 different materials, a 100 of each of three types, the properties of which change through time.  The variation is measured through an imperfection parameter which is determined twice daily.  For each material I have up to 50 days of data which can be plotted as a rising and falling chart of the evolving imperfection rate per sample.  I am looking for a statistical approach that:

1. measures the consistency of imperfection rates within each
   material type (is the behavior consistent or highly variable)
2. compares the different materials to determine if there is
   statistical different imperfection rates / behaviors

I am not sure where to start.  I obviously need a statistic that can compare time series (imperfection rates per day) - but I am not sure what that statistic is?

Any guidance appreciated ...

Comment: This is (or could be) an interesting Q, so I guess the 9 hours without any response tells you one thing: Your post contains too little information for anybody to engage with, so please consider editing the post as to: What do this imperfection parameter measure? how do you measure it? Can you show us some plots? Or even include (a link to) the data itself, or part of it, or some simulated similar data? ... Any covariates? ...

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  It will take me some time to construct the datasets ins a format that can be readily explored - but I will try and then update the question.